# Java: Read/Write a File and more

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I made a Class with 2 Methods which should handle either Writing in a file or reading from it.

Ive came up with something like this:

```
package YBot;
import java.io.*;



public class FollowerChecker {



public static StringBuilder sb;


    static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();

            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();

        }
    }



    public static void Writer() {

        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("donottouch.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.write(TwitchStatus.totalfollows);


        try {
            fw.write(sw.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now My Question is:

How can i add the function to create the "donottouch.txt" file if it doesnt exist already or  if its empty to write "0" in it?   when my program starts it will read the file for a number and later, if the number is changed it will rewrite it. so it would be the best that as soon it trys to read and its not there, it creates it right then and reread it. hope some1 can give me any examples =)

Comment: You can read the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handled it:

```
public static boolean checkIfExists(String path) {
    if (!new File(path).exists()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static String readFile(String file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null) {
        sb.append( line );
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();

}

public static void writeFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, 
                                                UnsupportedEncodingException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
    writer.println("0");
    writer.close();
    return;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*Gets absolute path to your project folder, assuming that is where
     * you are storing this text file. Otherwise hard code your path
     * accordingly.
     */
    File file = new File("");
    String fileGet = file.getAbsolutePath();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String path = sb.append(fileGet.toString() + "/donottouch.txt").toString();

    String result=null;

    if(!checkIfExists(path)) {
        try {
            writeFile(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("File created: 'donottouch.txt'");

    } else {
        try {
            result = readFile(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if( result.length() == 0 ) {
            try {
                writeFile(path);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("File amended: 'donottouch.txt'");
        }
        System.out.println("File exists: 'donottouch.txt'");
    }
}
```

Obviously I created a main class and did all of this outside of a class, unlike you, but it should be very simple to integrate. It is predicated on the presumption that you are storing your "donottouch.txt" in the source file of the project, however you can easily change the piece of code that grabs your absolute path to the hardcoded path of the folder in which you are looking. Hope this helps!

Comment: so how would i call your code to write the string i want to the file? on my code i just called FollowerChecker.Writer(); and it did write the string "totalfollows" to the file. i just dont understand the "path" thing of yours. the file is located in the project source.

Comment: The path is the absolute path to the file. It is merely a string with the structure, "/Users/YourName/PathToYourProjectFolder/.../donottouch.txt", so passing in the path is essentially passing in the file. This way you don't have to hardcode the whole path in case the folder moves. What the checkIfExists() method is doing is checking whether the "donottouch.txt" file exists in your project path, and if it does it is read via the readFile() method.  From here, if it is empty or if it doesn't exist, it is written with a "0" inside via the writeFile() method.

Comment: Did I answer your question? You may not be able to use the **exact** structure of my framework, but the methods there can be incorporated into your code. Hope this at least helps some :)

Comment: Well im still new to java so i dont understand all of it.. but i have to try i guess. Just gonna ask again if it doesnt work. thanks.

Comment: well im to stupid and my thing doesnt work anyway.. :(